# How to label payments in Gravity Forms Paypal Pro

Tags: paypal, gravity-forms-plugin

The Situation: My company wants to enable donations through their website. There are two ways a user can donate. 1. Technology. 2. Invest in a project.

The Set-Up: I am using Gravity Forms and PayPal Payments Pro add-on for payment processing on the website. ('Working Great.')

My Issue: I'de like to ensure that payments are labeled when they are passed to my PayPal account. I.E I want to know when someone donates where that money should go. Although all payments will go to one account. In paypal pro you can add comments to transactions. I need to be able to automatically add the comment when a form is submitted.

The solution: Use the below code to add a comment filter to gravity forms pay pal pro. So when the payment is processed for a given form, it also appears in my paypal account with a comment.

```
add_filter( 'gform_paypalpaymentspro_args_before_payment','add_donation_comment', 10, 2 );
function add_donation_comment( $args, $form_id ) { // do not edit $args or $form_id
    // apply to form 1 only
    if ( 1 == $form_id ) { // Replace '1' with your form id
        $args["COMMENT1"] = 'Field Project'; // Comment1 is the arg that paypal pro uses. 
    }
    // apply to form 2 only
    if ( 2 == $form_id ) { // Replace '2' with your form id
        $args["COMMENT1"] = 'Help Us Grow';
    }
    // always return the args, even if not changing anything 
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Did this solution work for you?  I implemented something similar but I am not seeing the comment in Paypal.

Comment: Hey @joeljoeljoel this did work for me. Are you using paypal regular or paypal pro? This comment will appear in the manager.paypal.com account. Also try using the gravity forms logging add-on to see if your site registers the comment.